# WPF Login Screen

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I have searched on Google about the login screens which are designed in WPF . I have to use one of the best login screens for my application. Is there any good login screens avaialble so that I can see them and choose one of them, I have no idea about a good design of a login screen. Please help me, thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://weblogs.asp.net/psheriff/archive/2009/10/27/create-a-login-window-in-wpf.aspx

Comment: Thanks Polaris, I have seen this, But I want stylish login screen.

Comment: You can easily take that window and style it the way you want with style sheets. This is most likely the most efficent login screen. Clean and simple.

Comment: yes, but I want to first look around for good idea on the net and then will look for my own